# Why AVCaptureVideoDataOutput doesn't give me supported highest resolution frame?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am working on iOS application which uses camera. I am using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` delegate method to get video frame. I always getting video frame with `1920 * 1080` regardless of device I am using which is iPhone X.

I am using `AVCaptureSession.Preset.high`

Here is my code snipped

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer))
    let image = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)
   }
```

When I do

```
    let device = AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: AVMediaType.video).first {
        ($0 as AVCaptureDevice).position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back
    }

    print("resolutions supported:: \(String(describing: device?.activeFormat.highResolutionStillImageDimensions)))")
```

This always gives me `3840 * 2160` for iPhone x which is having 12 megapixel

I am expecting same kind of highest possible resolution video frame through `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`.

I tried using `AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo` it also doesn't give me high resolution.

I did try `AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd4K3840x2160` which gives me expected resolution for frame but it may not work with older iPhone???

I know `AVCapturePhotoOutput` can give me higher resolution image. But for my use case I want to create image from video frame.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you use `canSetSessionPreset()` to see if `AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd4K3840x2160` is available and if it isn't use `.high`

Comment: @Spads I will try to use that but I am able to understand why setting preset ‘high’doesn’t give me highest possible resolution for video frame. Why I need to check and then apply 4K video preset. Is there any documentation Apple provides which says high preset can give at best 1920 * 1080 resolution

Comment: I tried the proposed 
        if (AVsession.canSetSessionPreset(AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd4K3840x2160)) {
            AVsession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd4K3840x2160
But now it fails to add the input. (iPhone 6). It works with next best hd1920x1080

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @adamfowlerphoto. And the answer Why you need to check and then apply 4K video preset is the function is according to hardware specification. Like, if your old phone doesn't have a high resolution sensor or lens which is good enough, you cannot use it;hd4K3840x2160